# string replace not working at all

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am reading a text file and I need to replace a few areas with new text that I marked with {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}.

So I load in the text, save it to a string variable, and then use String.Replace but it's not working.

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To 6
            fileText.Replace("{" & i & "}", DisplayStudentData(i))
        Next
```

And DisplayStudentData looks like this:

```
        Protected Function DisplayStudentData(ByVal itemNumber As Integer) As String

        Dim dsItem As String = ""
        If itemNumber <> -1 Then
            Select Case itemNumber
                Case 0
                    dsItem = "testFirstName"
                Case 1
                    dsItem = "testTitle"
                Case 2
                    dsItem = "testClass"
                Case 3
                    dsItem = "testTeacher"
                Case 4
                    dsItem = "testDept"
                Case 5
                    dsItem = "testEmail"
                Case 6
                    dsItem = "testPhone"
            End Select
        End If
        Return dsItem
    End Function
```

It seems like the above should work, but it doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Ok I figured it out...

I put all the data items into an array, then did this after loading the text file:

```
            fileText = String.Format(fileText, dArr(0), dArr(1), dArr(2), dArr(3), dArr(4), dArr(5), dArr(6))
```

Is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: What is not working about it exactly?  What is it doing exactly?  What have you done to figure it out, what sort of data are you dealing with?  Seems like your dealing with CSV type data, why are you choosing to read it this way, seems an odd way to read a file.

Comment: Im reading the file using StreamReader then storing the file in a String.  I then want to replace parts that are marked like {0},{1},{2} etc with "real" data.  The file writes out ok, but it still contains all my markers.

Comment: Ok I figured it out...see edits above

Comment: Since the indexes to the array line up, you should just be able to pass the array once, rather than individual elements: `fileText = String.Format(fileText, dArr)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fileText = fileText.Replace("{" & i & "}", DisplayStudentData(i))
```

Replace returns a **new** string. It does not modify the string from which it was called.

You could also do this:

```
fileText = String.Format(fileText, Enumerable.Range(0,7).Select(Function(i) DisplayStudentData(i)).ToArray())
```

Why isn't DisplayStudentData just an array in the first place (which would make string.Format() even easier)?

Comment: +1 Good answer. You beat me to it on the first point, and then as I was typing the `String.Format` method you beat me on that too lol.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  How could DisplayStudentData be an array?  I need to use the select case to pick which data item to return.  Thanks

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn initially you used loop to make {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6} and then the next line as you mentioned. Isn't this so much of code ?

Comment: What namespace is Enumerable in?  I can't seem to find it(.net 2.0)

Comment: I just found out that System.Linq isn't supported in my version of .NET

Answer (score 2):

on another note, If you know the string will always stay the same

you could do something like

```
dim myTestString = "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}"
dim result as string = string.format(myTeststring, "testFirstName", 
 "testTitle", "testClass", "testTeacher", "testDept", "testEmail", "testPhone")
```

you could always make it a property of your studentdata object.

Comment: Well it won't always be the same...{0}, {1}, {2} etc will always be in the text file, but the replacements will be different names, titles, etc...

Comment: I'll assume that your getting your information from a structure file (like excel).  Just read your row, replace "testFirstName" with the appropriate column etc.